# Re-Direct After Comment Submit IF Comment Comes from Sign-Up Page

Tags: comments, redirect

After having successfully done a custom version of the WordPress comments form into a "sign up" page, I now need to re-direct the user to a custom page upon submitting the "form".

The page is done and the slug of the page is `thank-you-for-signing-up`. Problem is, how do I check that the comments is coming from the `sign-up` page (slug: sign-up) and if so, re-direct to my custom page?

**This is the code I am trying to get working:**

```
add_filter('comment_post_redirect', 'sign_up_redirect');
function sign_up_redirect( $location ) {

        $signup_redirect = wp_redirect( home_url('/thank-you-for-signing-up/') );

    if ( is_page( 'sign-up' ) ) {

    return $signup_redirect;

    exit;

        }
}
```

**The signup template:**

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Signup
*/
get_header();
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="container">
To recieve updates and news, sign up using the form below.
We'll send over your account details within 24 hours.
<div style="margin-bottom:50px;"></div>
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('administrator')){
$qanda_info = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT comment_date_gmt, comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_author_IP
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT comment_date_gmt, comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_author_IP
FROM dev_comments
WHERE comment_post_ID = 70
) AS QANDA");
echo '<div style="margin-top:50px;"></div><div style="padding:20px;background-color:#fff;border:3px solid #333;border-radius:5px;"><ul>';
foreach($qanda_info as $info){
echo '<li><strong>'. $info->comment_date_gmt .'</strong> | '. $info->comment_author .' | '. $info->comment_author_email .' | IP-number: <small>'. $info->comment_author_IP .'</small></li>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';
}
comments_template('/signups.php');
?></div><?php
endwhile; endif;
get_footer();
```

**The signups "comment" form:**

```
<?php if (post_password_required()) return;
$signup_args = array(
'label_submit' => __('Sign Up', 'textdomain')
);
comment_form($signup_args);
```

That's all.

Comment: I'm going to assume the `wp_redirect()` and `exit` calls were just typos in the question... but your code would still not work, anyway.. so can you show the code you used for adding the comments form? Are you using a specific/custom Page template for the `sign-up` page? If so, can we see the full code?

Comment: Of ocurse, I can post that. Can you please explain what you mean about "typos"?

Comment: @SallyCJ updated as requested.

Comment: I was just saying you shouldn't call those in a *filter* hook like `comment_post_redirect`. Anyway, I'll check your updates and let you know later on.

Comment: Ah, okay. I hope that my question is clear, as what I need to do is check if the page is "signup" and if so and if someone posts a "comment" on that page - only then re-direct them to the "thanks for signing up" page.